# UiBinding.Binding returns NumberFormatException for Date

Tags: codenameone

I have a class which implements PropertyBusinessObject.One of the properties of the class is a Date as shown:

```
public class Appointment implements PropertyBusinessObject {
public final Property<Double, Appointment> id = new Property<>("id");
public final Property<Date, Appointment> bookDate = 
               new Property<> "bookDate", Date.class);
```

...

When I try and use UiBinding in a form as follows :

```
Appointment a = (Appointment) obj;
    for (UiBinding.Binding b : bindingList) {
        b.commit();           
    }
```

...

I get java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "Thu Oct 12 20:21:20 CAT 2017"

1. After digging around, I know that I should somehow use a DateConverter, but there is not enough information on how I can use this.

Comment: What Ui element are you trying to bind to? We usually bind date to a picker. Also what's the full stack trace of the exception?

Comment: Thanks Shai. I was binding to a TextField, but when I switched to a picker everything works as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now date only maps to picker. We might want to enhance it to support text field with `SimpleDateFormat` or something like that but right now that's not available.